# python lightweight-charts trying to get candles backwards

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, sleep

Is there a way to have the same result without using 2 data frames just one?

original code works with
#for i, series in df2.iterrows():

df1 is an static image with candles and df2 candles appear 1 by 1.

```py
import pandas as pd
from time import sleep
from lightweight_charts import Chart

if __name__ == '__main__':

    chart = Chart(toolbox=True)
    df1 = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_Daily1.csv')
    df2 = pd.read_csv('EURUSD_Daily2.csv')

    chart.set(df1)

    chart.show()

    
   
    #for i, series in df2.iterrows():
    for i, series in df2.iloc[::-1].iterrows():
            chart.update(series)
            sleep(0.1)
```

What I want to try is to get Panda to read backwards. Instead of the candles appearing one by one, the candles disappearing one by one.